# Vue provide+inject on the same component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I would like to pass `provide` and `inject` to a "page-section" component that could contain itself recursively using a `slot`.

The goal is for each one of these "page-section" components to pass its `id` concatenated after the rest of the passed down ids (separated by `/`) to create a path of all the containing components.

Some of the these "page-section" could also contain other types of components.

This is what I was trying unsuccessfully:

```
 Vue.component('text-input', {
      props: ['text', 'id'],
      template: '<input type="text" :value="text"',
      inject: ['sectionPath']
    });

    Vue.component('page-section', {
      props: ['id'],
      template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
      inject: {
        sectionPath: { default: '/' }
      },
      provide: {
        sectionPath: this.sectionPath + '/' + this.id
      }
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inject at the beginning, you can define as prop.

And you need to use function for provide to use context i believe.

```js
Vue.component('text-input', {
  props: ['text', 'id'],
  template: '<input type="text" :value="text" />',
  inject: ['sectionPath']
});

Vue.component('page-section', {
  template: '<div><slot></slot></div>',
  props: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
    sectionPath: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: '/'
    }
  }
  provide () {
    return {
      sectionPath: this.sectionPath + '/' + this.id
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Using the function form of provide fixed my issue. thanks